# How to resolve Out of memory if your procudure returns large number of records

Tags: java, sybase, resultset, scrollableresults

I am currently working on a Java application. The database used is Sybase ASE 15.0. Currently I am getting the following error in one of the scenarios:

> `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I have the following procedure call in my code:

```
CallableStatement cStmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
Connection con = getConnection();
cStmt = con.prepareCall("call <proc-name>(?,?)", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
boolean b;
// .....
// .....
while(rs.next()){
  List dList = new ArrayList();
  T t = new T();
  t.setProp1(rs.getBoolean("isAvailable"));
  t.setProp2(rs.getString("Name"));
  t.setDList(dList);
  ....
  ....
  t.setPropN(rs.getString("Property-name"));//many properties are read
  //  from db and POJO is populated.


  b = true;
  int Id = rs.getInt("Id");

  do{
     D d = new D();
     d.setProp1(rs.getFloat("<property-name"));
     ....
     ....
     d.setPropN(rs.getString("Property-name"));//many properties are read      
     dList.add(d);

     if(rs.next()){

         if(rs.getInt("Id")!=Id){
              b = false;
              rs.previous();    
         }

     } else {
             b = false;
             rs.previous();
     }
  } while (b);

  list.add(t);
}
```

The procedure receives date range as its arguments. If the date range is large, it returns large number of records. For small number of records, it is working fine, but for large records, it is giving 'out of memory' exception. I observed that if number of records is larger than 11997, then it gives this error.

I read that simple resultset stores records in heap memory, but it should work with scrollable resultset, right?

How do I remove this exception in this case.

Comment: What are you doing in the while loop with the results?

Comment: maybe related to the driver, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343703/how-to-create-a-scrollable-resultset)

Comment: Really depends on what r u doing among all records.. May be we could restrict the same using optimized query...

Comment: In while loop we are populating an arraylist and then all the objects in the arraylist are sent to a function which will download an excel sheet populated with all these records, Hence resultset.setFetchSize() method will not be useful as the function downloading an excel sheet requires entire arraylist of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using limits? If you can't limit the date range which could produce a huge dataset, you should use limits i.e. you do something with the first 100, then the next 100 etc. Then you have only the current 100 in the memory.

Comment: Can't use limits as I need to pass all the records in arraylist to a function which prints them in an excel file.

Comment: You can just write an excel in blocks. I.e. you write out the first 100 then the next etc. This is good because you dont need ALL the records in the memory at once. Of course you can set the limit to something bigger i.e. 1000.

Comment: Can you please show an example how to use limits to read data in the batch of 1000 rows using setFetchSize()?

Answer (score 0):

How about you simply increase the default max heap memory of your VM?

```
-Xmx<size> - to set the maximum Java heap size
-Xms<size> - to set the initial Java heap size
```

You can also try a profiler to pinpoint more accurately the memory leak. You have to be careful with that while loop and what you put in it and what is eligible for GC.

Check this informative article about the cost of object creation:

http://drmirror.net/2013/06/06/object-creation/

Good memory efficient practices for java : https://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pldi09tutorials/memory-efficient-java-tutorial.pdf

---

Updated:
In response to "Is there any other way that the result set does not read all records into memory simultaneously and read them in chunks? "
try using the setFetchSize on the ResultSet (rs)

Read more about setFetch size:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/858863/4807777

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20900045/4807777

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26235298/4807777

---

Update 2
In response to your loop code:

declare all your variables outside the loops and initialize them as you need;
So before the loop:

```
List dList;
T t;
int Id
D d;
while(rs.next()){
  dList = new ArrayList();
  t = new T();
  // and so on...

  list.add(t);
}
```

And then try again.

Comment: No increasing heap size is not an option. Is there any other way that the result set does not read all records into memory simultaneously and read them in chunks?

Comment: Hi Laurentiu, I went through the pdf with a bird's eye view, but on first thought, I think it will not help me. I will again read it thoroughly but it might not help. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you help me how to read all the records using setFetchSize() and how will it improve the performance?

Comment: The setFetchSize approach is not suitable in my case as in while loop we are populating an arraylist and then all the objects in the arraylist are sent to a function which will download an excel sheet populated with all these records, Hence resultset.setFetchSize() method will not be useful as the function downloading an excel sheet requires entire arraylist of objects. –

Comment: So then your problem is with the ArrayList you are populating. Share the code through which you do this (in other words the while content) in a relevant code form.

Comment: Updated the response according to your while loop code.

Comment: I already tried that, it does improve but not much. Still getting the same error of out of memory.

Comment: Post the line it encoutered the exception right before the stack trace print. Try logging the number of iterations for each of the loops and see how it differs from try to try. Also don't forget to close the result set.

Comment: I logged number of iterations. It iterates till 12000 to 13000 records and then throws out of memory exception from while loop only. The entire code is in try-catch-finally block. In finally block, I m closing resultset, but it does not reach there and throws Exception before that only. Then in finally it closes connection.

Comment: Try removing this code (seems like overhead) and try again if(rs.next()){

         if(rs.getInt("Id")!=Id){
              b = false;
              rs.previous();    
         }

     } else {
             b = false;
             rs.previous();
     }

Answer (score 0):

First just a resource cleanliness: use `try (ResultSet rs = cStmt.query()) { ... }` to close the resultset afterwards.

S**tore the result of the stored procedure in a (temporary) table**, and use a SELECT, possible paged. Then the result set can iterate. The **call** probably passes all data to JDBC. I do not know the stored procedure capabilities of sybase, but maybe you can do things there.

Check, use VARCHAR rather than CHAR or such.

Use UTF-8 rather than UTF-16LE.

On storing in java, maybe cache equal Strings/BigDecimals in an identity map so that only the first object instance is used in the data.